# Dynamic fields are not getting saved in database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database, wordpress

I'm writing a code to add the dynamic fields and save them to the database, but when I save it's not getting saved, below is my code, can anyone please tell what am I doing wrong
This is a plugin code where in I have added the form to dynamically add fields and save it data
This is form code:

```
    <?php
/*
Plugin Name: Link Changer
Description: Changes the button link after certain clicks
Version: 1.0
Text Domain: button-link-changer

*/


 if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
        exit; // Exit if accessed directly
    }

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'link_changer_menu' );


$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','aejaz_wp1','Q.gslkbUNCOT2zZUVSw82','aejaz_wp1');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
else{
    echo '';
}


global $jal_db_version;
$jal_db_version = '1.0';

function jal_install() {
    global $wpdb;
    global $jal_db_version;

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'liveshoutbox';

    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
        id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        links varchar(55) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
        hitsmade mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
        hitstocount mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  (id)
    ) $charset_collate;";

    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    dbDelta( $sql );

    add_option( 'jal_db_version', $jal_db_version );
}

function jal_install_data() {
    global $wpdb;

    $welcome_name = 'Mr. WordPress';
    $welcome_text = 'Congratulations, you just completed the installation!';

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'liveshoutbox';

    $wpdb->insert( 
        $table_name, 
        array( 
            'time' => current_time( 'mysql' ), 
            'name' => $welcome_name, 
            'text' => $welcome_text, 
        ) 
    );
}

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'jal_install' );
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'jal_install_data' );

function link_changer_menu(){

  $page_title = 'Link Changer';
  $menu_title = 'Button Link Changer';
  $capability = 'manage_options';
  $menu_slug  = 'Button-Link-Changer';
  $function   = 'extra_post_info_page';
  $icon_url   = 'dashicons-media-code';
  $position   = 6;

  add_menu_page( $page_title,
                 $menu_title, 
                 $capability, 
                 $menu_slug, 
                 $function, 
                 $icon_url, 
                 $position );

add_action( 'admin_init', 'link_register_settings' ); 
}

    function link_register_settings() {   

   // Let's create and register the Sections. 
// - register_setting( $option_group, $option_name, $sanitize_callback );
    register_setting('button-link-changer', 'link_options', 'link_options_sanitize');
} 

//to save options as array create input fields
function bp_options_sanitize($input){
    $input['link_one'] = sanitize_text_field($input['link_one']);
    $input['link_two'] = sanitize_text_field($input['link_two']);
    $input['link_hits'] = sanitize_text_field($input['link_hits']);
    $input['links'] = sanitize_text_field($input['links']);
    return $input;
} // end link_options_sanitize

// Let's create the Main Page


function extra_post_info_page(){

 #saving plugin options to database from form ?>  

<h1>Button Link Changer</h1>   
    <form method="post" action="options.php">    
        <?php settings_fields( 'button-link-changer' ); ?>   
        <?php //do_settings_sections( 'button-link-changer' ); ?>    
        <?php $link_options = get_option('link_options') ?>
        <table class="form-table">    
           <tr valign="top">
                    <th scope="row">Link one</th>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="link_options[link_one]" value="<?php echo esc_attr($link_options['link_one']); ?>" />
                    </td>
           </tr>

                <tr valign="top">
                    <th scope="row">Link two</th>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="link_options[link_two]" value="<?php echo esc_attr($link_options['link_two']) ?>" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr valign="top">
                    <th scope="row">Link Hits</th>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="link_options[link_hits]" value="<?php echo esc_attr($link_options['link_hits']) ?>" />
                    </td>
                </tr>

        </table>    
                    <?php submit_button(); ?> 
    </form>  


     <form name="add_me" id="add_me">
        <table id="dynamic">
            <input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Enter Your Name" />
            <button type="button" name="add" id="add_input">Add</button>
        </table>
        <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-rc1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var i = 1;
            $('#add_input').click(function() {
                i++;
                $('#dynamic').append('<tr id="row' + i + '" ><td><input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Enter Your Name"/></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="' + i + '" class="btn_remove">Remove</button></td></tr>');
            });
            $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function() {
                var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
                $('#row' + button_id + '').remove();
            });
            $('#submit').click(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "insert.php",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: $('#add_me').serialize(),
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert(data);
                        $('#add_me')[0].reset();
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>             
<?php

//fetching data from database
global $wpdb;

$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT option_value FROM $wpdb->options WHERE option_name='link_options'"); 

if(!empty($results)) {
    // output data of each row
     $arrayvalues=$results[0]->option_value;

$unserialized_categoriesx =  unserialize($arrayvalues);
echo $unserialized_categoriesx['link_one'];
$varlinkone = $unserialized_categoriesx['link_one'];
 echo "</br>"; 
echo $unserialized_categoriesx['link_two'];
$varlinktwo = $unserialized_categoriesx['link_two'];

$unserialized_categoriesx['link_hits'];
 $varlinkhits  =$unserialized_categoriesx['link_hits'];
} 


$hits = 0;
//counting and comparing hits


if ($hits[0]<= $varlinkhits)
{
$buttonlink="$varlinkone";
}
else
{
$buttonlink="$varlinktwo";
}
echo $hits[0];
?>
 <a href="<?php echo $_SESSION["button_url"] ?>" >Join Whatsapp Group</a>;

<?php

$_SESSION["button_url"] = $buttonlink;
?> 

<?php

}
function link_button_function()  {?>

    <a href="<?php echo $_SESSION["button_url"] ?>" id="clickme">Join Whatsapp Group</a>;

 <?php }
add_shortcode('button_link', 'link_button_function');
```

This is insert.php

```
 <?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "aejaz_wp1");
$number = count($_POST["name"]);
if($number > 0)
{
 for($i=0; $i<$number; $i++)
 {
 if(trim($_POST["name"][$i] != ''))
 {
 $sql = "INSERT INTO wp_liveshoutbox(links) VALUES('".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["name"][$i])."')";
 mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
 }
 }
 echo "Data Inserted Successfully";
}
else
{
 echo "Enter Your Name";
}
?>
```

Comment: First thing I would do is first decide were the problem is, is it your JS or PHP.  What I would do is either `console.log($('#add_me').serialize())`, or alternatively look in your browsers network tab and see what's been sent.  If this looks OK, then it's the PHP side.

Comment: @Keith Sorry, but I'm quite unsure about what data to check in network tab, as I can see there is no console error, actually this is a plugin code if you want I've posted the complete code in the question for you, can you please check

Comment: To get to Developer mode in chrome in say windows you can do `Ctrl+Shift+I`.  Other browsers / OS might be slightly different.  Once you have this you should see a tab called network, click on this and you should see a request for `insert.php`, if you click this on the right you should see what the `request / response` was.

Comment: The request is not going to insert.php, I can' see that file in network tab

Comment: If your not seeing the request in your network tab, that would suggest to me it's something Javascript end.  If you `console.log($('#add_me').serialize())`  before doing your ajax, and then look at console does that look correct?.

Comment: I have tested with ajax, but since it's not working, I was doing it with form action="", now still the value doesn't get save! could you please check it by logging in, if you could provide me your mail, I can send you the credentials